# CSS use color from another class?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-variables

Is it possible to import a color from one CSS class to another? Or create some sort of global color define and then use it in multiple classes so that doesn't have to be updated in multiple places if you want to change a color?

For example say I have a CSS class that I want to use for specific elements but I want it to use the same color assigned to the Bootstrap "danger" class. Is there any way to do that? Or do I just have to copy the color value from the Bootstrap CSS file and use it in my own class?

Comment: Pure CSS does not allow to do such things, what you need is called css preprocessor. There are a few css preprocessors: SCSS, SASS, LESS etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may also want to look at the new [CSS variables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#examples) in Bootstrap 4. They will let you override colors, but you'll need to redefine the CSS class.

> CSS variables offer similar flexibility to Sass’s variables, but
>   without the need for compilation before being served to the browser.

For example:

```
.text-teal {
  color: var(--teal);
}
```

Bootstrap 4 [CSS Variables Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/gMBtn0MHBt/bootstrap-4-css-variables)

Comment: Cool, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: One more question.... is it possible to darken/lighten a color in CSS? Like use one of these colors, but slightly darker or lighter for :hover?

Answer (score 1):

Use SCSS

Assign variables:

```
$darkGrey: #7a7a7a;
```

Use those variables:

```
ul, .hero, .homepage, .anotherClass {
  background: $darkGrey;
}
```

More here: https://responsivedesign.is/articles/difference-between-sass-and-scss/

Answer (score 1):

You can assign global color in ::root selector like an example below:

```
:root{
     --green-color:#fff123;
}
```

and use this color any where with var() function in css like:

```
.container{
    background-color:var(--green-color);
}

.column{
   color:var(--green-color);
}
```